# Communicate password securely to another program (separate shell/dbus)

Tags: linux, bash, dbus

I am writing a build script which has some password protected files (keys). I need a way to prompt the user once for the password and then use this key across multiple scripts. These scripts do not live inside the same shell, and may spawn other windows via dbus. I can then send them commands, one of which must have access to the password.

I have this working already, but at a few points the passphrase is either used directly on a command-line (passed via dbus), or is put into a file (the name then passed to the other script). Both of these are less secure than I want*. The command-line ends up in a history which may be stored in a file, as well as appearing in the process list, and the second option stores in a file which can be read by somebody else.

Is there some standard way to create a temporary communications channel between two processes which could communicate the password and not be intercepted by another user on the system (including root)?

**Note: This is primarily an exercise to be fully secure. For my current project the temporary in-file storage of the password is okay.*

Comment: The *including root* part makes it difficult to imagine a solution which could not be breached. Root could ultimately install custom kernel modules to track every byte transferred within the system. You can run but you can't hide...

Comment: I guess I'm only interested in security from non-extraordinary measures. Something secure enough so root on a standard install could not gain access with a limited few commands. Or at least something that doesn't involve writing to the disk, which may end up being seen by somebody other than root (think of hosted providers).

Comment: You can *send them commands*? How? If done through socket etc, could you send the password also? Or could you spawn all scripts with a temporary token which they can use to *phone home* and ask for the password when needed?

Comment: I'm sending commands to the shells with `qdbus`. The sending I think is secure enough for my needs (only in memory), but the command is then executed on the shell, thus ending up in the history.

Comment: It would help if you could show a *minimal* POC which can be replicated. Difficult to know your exact setup.

Comment: Invoking the scripts, is there any point in time when commands are *not* saved to shell history? Like when you start the other shells - is that done from you master script or before-hand? We need a testable POC

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am trying  to do something similar and would love to see your solution.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan I haven't looked at it in a while, but I never did find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Setting "root being all-powerful" aside, I would imagine that a [Private DBus Connection](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/api/html/group__DBusConnection.html#ga434e3fc7ee420fd30e2f05e57ff26b1d) would do the trick although the documentation I could find seems a little light on what exactly makes a private connection private.

However, [the DBus Specification](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html), more specifically, the  [Message Bus Specification](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#message-bus) subsection on eavesdropping says in part:

> Receiving a unicast message whose DESTINATION indicates a different
>   recipient is called eavesdropping. On a message bus which acts as a
>   security boundary (like the standard system bus), the security policy
>   should usually prevent eavesdropping, since unicast messages are
>   normally kept private and may contain security-sensitive information.

So you may not even need to use private connections which incur more overhead costs.  But on a risk/reward basis with security being paramount, that may be the more secure alternative for you.  Hope that helps.